# PowerShell: How to display in full?

Tags: windows, powershell, security, command-line, findstr

I tried running the following command in PS:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | findstr 4720
```

The result I got seems to be squished as if the column widths need to be adjusted. How can I view all the text that is after the ellipses (...)? See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGqzn.png

How to view the returned info in full?

Comment: Use `Format-Table -Auto -Wrap`

Answer (score 2):

As Santiago mentioned you can use `Format-Table`.

Though since it looks like you're looking for a specific Event ID, I'd recommend instead of using `findstr` (which may return unrelated results as it's searching for '4720' anywhere in your results - unless that's your intention of course) instead target the attribute using the `Where-Object` cmdlet (or its' alias `?`). Also, if you want a "pure" PowerShell solution I'd recommend using `Select-String` instead of `findstr`

E.g.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 4720} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer from @Novalis, Where-Object like that is definitely faster than findstr, and the Format-Table should sort out the ... you're seeing.

But to take it one step further an even faster method is to use -FilterHashtable. Specifically :

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4720} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

The reason it's faster is because when using Where-Object you're asking the system for ALL of the system logs, and then once received by your script you're then filtering them out (same with findstr). FilterHashtable just requests the log entries from system that match the require event ID, so less data needs to be sent to your script.

Comment: Excellent point about filtering _at the source_.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It worked to a certain extent. the -Autosize did not work: https://i.imgur.com/RTgJ2AP.png   -- Ideally, the format table would be great if I could get the columns to show in its entirety 

If I add -Wrap to the end, it would be way too long to find something specific since there are hundreds/thousands of entries.

Comment: Yeah forgot to add -wrap. If you have a lot of entries, once you've quickly filtered out the rest as you've done already, it's then that you might want to locally filter. Eg, pipe the Get-WinEvent to Where {$_.Message -like "*someStringToSearch*"}, to just get those results that contain the specied word/string/name etc.